# Vue-Router not working with params and queries at same time

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I’m trying to use a push like this:

```js
// Expected Output: localhost:8080/#/app/:org/dashboard/?client=:id
// Output: localhost:8080/#/app/:org/dashboard/

this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard", params: { organization: this.organization.name }, query: { client: this.client.id } })
```

But vue-router only uses the param, and ignores my queries, am I doing something wrong or need to set a config for this?

```js
// My router

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/app/:organization",
        name: "Authenticated",
        component: Authenticated,
        children: [
            {
                path: "dashboard",
                name: "dashboard",
                component: Dashboard,
                meta: {
                    breadcrumb: [
                        { name: "Dashboard", link: "" }
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: how did you define that route?

Comment: added my router

Comment: please look at this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode

Comment: so instead of using queries, use props you mean ?

Comment: cast queries to props and use that props, i'm not sure if that will work

Comment: It should but my app is quite big and changing from every query to props might be a problem, does vue limit us to only use query or params ?

Comment: i don't know i'm searching and i hope that i could find a solutio

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I had a user permission manager screwing with my navigation. This should be working!

Comment: ah ok, but how do you try to solve this

Comment: it's hard to add the solution to context because I made a permission manager, and the permission manager was trying to force push the param and that replaced the queries when navigating to the new link